# The "n identical lines skipped" message within edits appears to break code formatting

Tags: bug, review-queues, code-formatting

I've just completed this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4967134 At first I was going to reject it as it appeared to be too minor, but then I noticed the paragraph at the end, with the exception of the blockquote, is correctly wrapped in inline code tags (`like this`).

However it seems due to the identical lines skipped message, the formatting has no longer applied:

[image: Example]

On the [content itself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24009541/2) after the edit was accepted, the code is correctly formatted:

[image: Content Example]

I can only assume this is caused by the "10 identical lines skipped" message within the edit review?