# Has Meta's unknowingly broken Tumbleweed badge been fixed?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges, tumbleweed-badge

3 hours ago I earned a Tumbleweed badge [here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed?userid=1317805). Woo!

Anyway, the Tumbleweed badge description states:

> Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views **for a week**.

However the question it was awarded for was asked [over 2 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258157/the-n-identical-lines-skipped-message-within-edits-appears-to-break-code-forma).

Checking out the [list of other users with the Tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) I can see that 4 of them were awarded 6 hours ago and a further 4 were awarded 3 hours ago (when I got mine). Interestingly, all 8 of these were for questions asked in the first half of 2014.

Visiting the end of the list it becomes clear that the first Tumbleweed badge was awarded on Meta in April 2014, however my question specifically was asked in June 2014. In June 2014, several users were awarded with this badge, so somehow my question was ignored.

I can only assume whatever the problem was is fixed now and that over the next 24 hours a load more badges will be awarded, but I'd like to ask: what went wrong?

---

Two days later and no further Tumbleweed badges have been awarded. Assuming now that this is an issue which only affected these questions specifically: What happened to mine and the 7 other questions which had to wait 2 years for the badge to be awarded?

Comment: [Related?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344403/4074148) *A comment on the question was deleted, making it eligible to the badge...*

Comment: @Veve not sure. In my situation myself and 3 others all received these badges at the exact time. A couple of hours earlier, 4 others also received the badge at the exact same time. It could simply be that a user had left a comment on all of these and had been purged, but that seems a little too coincidental.