# Tumbleweed after very long time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tumbleweed-badge

As per the scenario tumbleweed badge will granted after a week. But from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881840/http-request-non-keepalive-persistent) question, user get badge after 10 month. Badge given can be seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63?page=3). So I wonder there is something missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment on the question was deleted, making it eligible to the badge...

The comment was deleted a bit before the badge was awarded, so the timeline fits.